# No Output in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am very new in the programming world, but I have been building some python code where it solves most of the calculation which I am doing in the school.
All good, but!
I would like to share the program with my colleagues, and I am trying to make it as simple is possible for them to use it, but it is a lot more difficult for me to do it, because I have to start everything again in JavaScript.
I do not find why after I input the number and press the button does not happen anything. I have tried different variations on the code, but still no output.
Thank you!

```js
function rf() {
  var voltNominal = 230;
  var multiplyfactor = 5;
  var rFSikring = parseInt(document.getElementById("rFSikring").value);
  var rFSikringTotal = voltNominal / (multiplyfactor * rFSikring);
  document.getElementsById('rFSikringTotal').innerHTML = rFSikringTotal;
}
```

```html
<p>Welcome to IKmin Calculator!</p>
<p>Enter the RF sikring Value: <input type="number" id="rFSikring"> <button oneclick="rf()">Submit</button></p>
<span id="rFSikringTotal"></span>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the commenters have pointed out, there are just a couple of typo's that are preventing the code from executing.

```js
function rf() {
  var voltNominal = 230;
  var multiplyfactor = 5;
  var rFSikring = parseInt(document.getElementById("rFSikring").value);
  var rFSikringTotal = voltNominal / (multiplyfactor * rFSikring);
  document.getElementById('rFSikringTotal').innerHTML = rFSikringTotal;
}
```

```html
<p>Welcome to IKmin Calculator!</p>
<p>Enter the RF sikring Value: <input type="number" id="rFSikring"> <button onclick="rf()">Submit</button></p>
<span id="rFSikringTotal"></span>
```